# tsne.fit_transform(final_embeddings(...) - ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I have been running this https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py on ipython notebook but I am getting this error:

This is a snapshot of the complete error message: 
https://postimg.org/image/c3fzj8gif/

My envirmonet is:

- numpy '1.11.0'
- scipy '0.17.0'
- under anaconda python 2.7

Any idea? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does your program download the data successfully? Did you see this output at all before the error messages?

```
Found and verified text8.zip
Data size 17005207
Most common words (+UNK) [['UNK', 418391], ('the', 1061396), ('of', 593677), ('and', 416629), ('one', 411764)]
Sample data [5241, 3083, 12, 6, 195, 2, 3136, 46, 59, 156] ['anarchism', 'originated', 'as', 'a', 'term', 'of', 'abuse', 'first', 'used', 'against']
```

Comment: Almost the same, this is what I'm getting: Found and verified text8.zip // 
Data size 17005207 // Most common words (+UNK) [['UNK', 418391], ('the', 1061396), ('of', 593677), ('and', 416629), ('one', 411764)] // 
Sample data [5239, 3084, 12, 6, 195, 2, 3137, 46, 59, 156] //